# Update an order after POST method Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework

I just started learning Django Rest Framework together with React and i am stuck on this problem for a couple of weeks now. Hope you guys can help me out.. Here's what i am trying to achieve: When a user clicks on 'Buy Now' there will be an order created with the **status** of the order set to **open**. This all works fine. My **Orders** view & model looks like this:

```
class OrdersView(ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = OrdersSerializer
queryset = Orders.objects.all()

def post(self, request):
    serializer = OrdersSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        data = serializer.validated_data
        price = data['price']
        pakket = data['pakket']
        payment = mollie_client.payments.create({
            'amount': {
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'value': price,
            },
            'description': pakket,
            'redirectUrl': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/Thanks',
            'webhookUrl': 'http://6efd85bb183c.ngrok.io/api/order-status/',
            'method': 'ideal',
        })
        serializer.save(user=request.user, userID=request.user.id,
                        status=payment.status, orderID=payment.id)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=payment)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class Orders(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pakket = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=one_hour_later)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    orderID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.EmailField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

My serializer called **OrdersSerializer** looks like this:

```
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user','status','orderID','userID')
```

After the status of the order has changed (the user made the purchase or not) my webhook is called (a POST) and i am retreiving the order by the **id** which is POSTED to the webhook. This is all taken care of by using an API client (mollie_client). This all works fine too. My View looks like this:

```
class OrderStatusView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer
    queryset = Orders.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        payment_id = data['id']
        payment = mollie_client.payments.get(payment_id)
        if payment.is_paid():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=payment.status)
        elif payment.is_pending():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=payment.status)
        elif payment.is_open():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=payment.status)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=payment.status)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now my problem is: How do i retreive the original Order (by the id) and **update** the status of the order.
Grabbing the payment.status works fine, but how do i grab the Order and update its status from the payment.status?

I am able to grab the original order by: **Orders.objects.get(orderID=payment_id)** inside the view, but from there i am stuck. I am not sure how i can update that specific order and change the status to payment.status.
I am thinking i have to do something with the **serializer.save(status=payment.status)**.
Maybe it is super simple, but i can't get my head around it.

Hope its clear and you guys can help.
Please keep in mind i am still a beginner on this topic.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Comment: i dont see any relation `payment` and `Order`. Are you sure you can find `orderID` by `payment_id`? And always want update this `Order` status same `payment.status` ? Better you can update `Payment` model in question.

Comment: I've added the OrdersView on top, which creates the initial order.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ngoc Pham pointed out It is better to keep payment and order different. What is generally followed is You keep pinging for the payment status of an order and then update the order status with choice field.
In Orders Model you can define a choice field for status and whenever you are buying create an order with its status to constants.PENDING.
Now filter all the orders with status as pending and hit the check_payment_status of api with the order id. And now if the payment status is success then update the order object with constants.SUCCESS. Here's a gist of what I meant.

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'pending'
    SUCCESS = 'success'
    FAILURE = 'failure'
    ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PENDING, "pending"),
        (SUCCESS, "success"),
        (FAILURE, "failure"),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
         choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES,
         max_length=10,
         null=True
    )
```

Now whenever you buy make the status as

```
status=Orders.PENDING
```

if the payment status is pending. And then fetch the orders object to get the pending objects

```
Orders.objects.filter(status=Orders.PENDING)
```

Once you iterate through this queryset you can hit payment_status_check request for a particular id and update the status again through

```
status=Orders.SUCCESS
```

Hope this gives you a way to approach this problem :).

Answer (score 0):

First, your `OrderStatusView` post never throw `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`. Its have `else` condition in last. It always return HTTP_200_OK.

you can try edit like this: its can find orders have `orderID=payment_id`, and if not have anything match, return `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`. Make sure all status of `payment` is same with status of `Order`

```
class OrderStatusView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer
    queryset = Orders.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        payment_id = data['id']
        payment = mollie_client.payments.get(payment_id)
        orders = self.get_queryset().filter(orderID=payment_id)
        if not orders:
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        orders.update(status=payment.status)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=payment.status)
```